# How to recover a utility. (Accidentally Deleted /usr/bin/php file)

Tags: package-management, software-installation, linux-mint, php

New Linux user. I accidentally overwrote my /usr/bin/php file. The php command no longer works.

What's the best way to recover that file?

Using bash and Linux Mint distro.

Comment: reinstall php again run `sudo apt-get install php5 libapache2-mod-php5` if it shows it exits remove php and install it again

Comment: Thanks. So my problem was that I was reinstalling php5 and not php5-cli.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
sudo apt-get remove php5-cli
sudo apt-get install php5-cli
```

And the one liner,

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall php5-cli
```

Comment: Why not only `sudo apt-get install --reinstall php5-cli`?

Comment: @manatwork Thanks. I have added. In fact I didn't know it.

Answer (score 3):

The easiest way is to reinstall the package containing the file you accidentally deleted. I'll explain how to do this from the command line, on distributions using Debian packaging tools (Debian, Ubuntu, Mint, …). If you use a package management GUI, it may have equivalent commands. All the commands mentioned here, except for the ones that only display information and don't modify the system, must be executed as root (i.e. put `sudo` in front or run them in a root shell).

First, find out which package contains the file. You can use the command `dpkg -S /usr/bin/php5` for that. Here, the (relevant) result is `php5-cli`. There's a subtlety here: this package contains `/usr/bin/php5`, not `/usr/bin/php`; the package creates a symbolic link `/usr/bin/php` which points indirectly to `/usr/bin/php5` upon installation.

If you're missing `/usr/bin/php5`, reinstall the `php5-cli` package. On the command line, use `apt-get --reinstall install` or `aptitude reinstall` to force a reinstallation even if the package is marked as up-to-date.

If you're missing `/usr/bin/php`, recreate the symbolic link. You can do this manually: `ln -s /etc/alternatives/php /usr/bin/php`. If you reinstall the package as above, this will recreate the symbolic link.

If you're missing `/etc/alternatives/php`, run `update-alternatives --auto php` (or run `update-alternatives --config php` and select `php5` in the list).

Summary:

```
dpkg -S /usr/bin/php
sudo apt-get --reinstall reinstall php5-cli
sudo update-alternatives --auto php
```